# Count Pictures with power Automate in Web

Tags: web-scraping, power-automate, power-automate-desktop

I´m currently building a small Power Automate flow to collect some data from a Website. This has been working well until now because I have to count small pictures (picture below).

[image: screenshot]

I need to know how many white/black circles there are.
Here´s the link (pictures in the top-right corner):

https://www.fondsprofessionell.de/fonds/details/fondsName/Lupus-alpha-Micro-Champions-CAV/ISIN/LU0218245263/fondsID/FU_100019365/

I tried to use the block "get details from web page" but can't find "rating_black" there (that is the name of the pictures).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the value from the website using the 'Run Javascript function on web page' action (copy and paste this to PAD):

```
WebAutomation.ExecuteJavascript BrowserInstance: Browser Javascript: $'''function ExecuteScript() { /*your code here, return something (optionally); */ 

return $(\'table.fondsRating > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > img[src*=\"black\"]\').length;
}''' Result=> Result
```

or alternatively without javascript you can use a CSS selector.

It looks like this will always have 6 images and always in the same position within html.

so you can add a ***UI Element***, doesn't really matter which one as you will change the selector using a variable.
paste this in a PAD flow:

```
WebAutomation.LaunchChrome.AttachToChromeByUrl TabUrl: $'''https://www.fondsprofessionell.de/fonds/details/fondsName/Lupus-alpha-Micro-Champions-CAV/ISIN/LU0218245263/fondsID/FU_100019365/''' AttachTimeout: 5 BrowserInstance=> Browser
SET blackCount TO 0
LOOP LoopIndex FROM 0 TO 5 STEP 1
    SET elementSelector TO $'''table[class=\"fondsRating\"] > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > img:nth(%loopIndex%)'''
    WebAutomation.GetDetailsOfElement BrowserInstance: Browser Control: appmask['Web Page \'h ... 100019365/\'']['imgElement'] AttributeName: $'''Source Link''' AttributeValue=> AttributeValue
    IF Contains(AttributeValue, $'''rating_black''', True) THEN
        Variables.IncreaseVariable Value: blackCount IncrementValue: 1
    END
END
Display.ShowMessageDialog.ShowMessage Title: $'''Black dots''' Message: blackCount Icon: Display.Icon.None Buttons: Display.Buttons.OK DefaultButton: Display.DefaultButton.Button1 IsTopMost: False ButtonPressed=> ButtonPressed
```

It should look similar to this:

[image: FlowLayout]

then edit your UI Element change the Default Selector to use Text and set the value to the variable:
[image: UIElementSelector]

Using the CSS selector adds a lot of flexibility to your flow, you can re-use one UI element for several elements as long as you change the selector value.